# Emacs Prelude key binding for bury-buffer

Tags: key-bindings, buffers, prelude

Does Emacs Prelude provide a key binding for `bury-buffer`, which I use very frequently?

Answer (score 2):

No. Set it yourself, e.g. `(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-b") 'bury-buffer)`.

Answer (score 1):

As [Heikki correctly points out](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/37377/15748), Prelude does not bind `bury-buffer` for your convenience, so you should do it yourself. I would additionally like to offer a couple of suggestions which make un/burying buffers more convenient for me:

```el
(defun my-bury-buffer (&optional buffer-or-name unbury)
  "Un/bury buffer.
With prefix argument UNBURY, call `unbury-buffer'. Otherwise pass
BUFFER-OR-NAME to `bury-buffer'."
  (interactive "i\nP")
  (if unbury
      (unbury-buffer)
    (bury-buffer buffer-or-name)))

;; Sample key binding
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x B") #'my-bury-buffer)
```

This allows me to bury and unbury buffers with a single global key binding.

A more general approach to unburying is to enable `winner-mode`.

Quoth [`(emacs) Window Convenience`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Window-Convenience.html):

```
Winner mode is a global minor mode that records the changes in the
window configuration (i.e., how the frames are partitioned into
windows), so that you can undo them.  You can toggle Winner mode with
‘M-x winner-mode’, or by customizing the variable ‘winner-mode’.  When
the mode is enabled, ‘C-c left’ (‘winner-undo’) undoes the last window
configuration change.  If you change your mind while undoing, you can
redo the changes you had undone using ‘C-c right’ (‘M-x winner-redo’).
```

With `winner-mode` enabled, you can type <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> to bury, unbury, bury a bit deeper, unbury Kill Bill-style, etc. not just buffers but entire window configurations, too. It's basically window management for cats.

Comment: C-h k for C-x B says it's already bound. I'm guessing thats not a big problem.  "C-x b (translated from C-x B) runs the command switch-to-buffer (found
in global-map), which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
`window.el'."

Comment: @joshsverns Emacs defaults to folding lower- and upper-case letters to the same key binding. If you bind `C-x B` explicitly Emacs will distinguish it from `C-x b`, so there's no issue with using `C-x B`. This particular key just happens to be the one I use; you're free to pick any key that tickles your fancy.